# How to set the width of a div which should be equal to the table?

Tags: html, css

i have a html snippet like this

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <table id="table">
  </table>
</div>
```

i want the width of `div1` always to be equal to the width of the `table`
How can i achieve that?

Comment: with CSS it's impossible with this HTML, so forget it ... now consider JS/jQuery

Comment: Put .wrapper1 and .wrapper2 both in an inline-block container. https://jsfiddle.net/1sckoowm/2/

Comment: @MrLister this will simply make the wider one control the size https://jsfiddle.net/1sckoowm/6/

Comment: Rather than say "I have this markup so how can I achieve this style", can you provide an example of what you want it to look like? I have a feeling there's a simpler way. Asking the correct question you actually want to be answered is often the hardest part.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're right, I was a bit quick on the draw. How about [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sckoowm/16/).

Comment: @MrLister here you cheated a bit with a non supported value :p ... by the way i suspect there will be more content in both wrapper as if not, we can ommit them and we have the div and the table as sibling and it can be easier to find supported work around

Comment: i want it to use as a horizontal scrollbar, that is placed above the table

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like this:

```
<style>
   .container
   {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
   }

   .wrapper01
   {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
   }

   .wrapper02
   {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
   }

   .div1
   {
      width: 100%;
   }

   #table
   {
      width: 100%;
   }

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper01">
        <div class="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper02">
        <table id="table">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope my answer helped.

Answer (score -3):

I want to give you a simple example hope it helps

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*you can set width of your table same as your div one, used percent*/
    /*example*/

    #table1{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .div1{
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>

<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <table id="table">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a) cheating, and b) it doesn't work on account of the typo.

Comment: Well just an example, Your problem is just an easy..try to study more css or html